# How to reduce size of merged pdf and speed up merging operation with PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, size, pdfbox, reduce

We are using PDFBox 2.0.17  (main reason:free) with java 8 to merge two types of PDF documents (Normal PDF/A and converted PDF from Tiff file).

We found that the size of resulting PDF file is quite big - basically the total size of the all PDFs. I am trying to find a way to reduce the resulting file size.

I found a stackoverflow link [How to reduce the size of merged PDF/A-1b files with pdfbox or other java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420344/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-merged-pdf-a-1b-files-with-pdfbox-or-other-java-library). But it did not seem to help.

Is there any way to reduce the size of resulting PDF through the following ?

- Font optimization, Image optimization & compression PDF compression

---

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSBase;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

public class MergerTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  File file1 = new File("C:\\Test\\PdfBox_Examples\\doc1.pdf");        
  File file2 = new File("C:\\Test\\PdfBox_Examples\\doc2.pdf");  

  //Instantiating PDFMergerUtility class
  PDFMergerUtility PDFmerger = new PDFMergerUtility();

  //Setting the destination file
PDFmerger.setDestinationFileName("C:\\Test\\PdfBox_Examples\\merged.pdf");

  //adding the source files
  PDFmerger.addSource(file1);
  PDFmerger.addSource(file2);

  //Merging the two documents
  PDFmerger.mergeDocuments(null);

  System.out.println("Documents merged");

  File file = new File("C:\\Test\\PdfBox_Examples\\merged.pdf");
  PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
  Map<String, COSBase> fontFileCache = new HashMap<>();
  for (int pageNumber = 0; pageNumber < doc.getNumberOfPages(); 
      pageNumber++) {
      final PDPage page = doc.getPage(pageNumber);
      COSDictionary pageDictionary = (COSDictionary) 
      page.getResources().getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject
      (COSName.FONT);
      if(pageDictionary !=null) {
          for (COSName currentFont : pageDictionary.keySet()) {
              COSDictionary fontDictionary = (COSDictionary) 
         pageDictionary.getDictionaryObject(currentFont);
              for (COSName actualFont : fontDictionary.keySet()) {
                  COSBase actualFontDictionaryObject = 
      fontDictionary.getDictionaryObject(actualFont);
                  if (actualFontDictionaryObject instanceof COSDictionary) 
          {
                      COSDictionary fontFile = (COSDictionary) 
           actualFontDictionaryObject;
                      if (fontFile.getItem(COSName.FONT_NAME) instanceof 
           COSName) {
                          COSName fontName = (COSName) 
                fontFile.getItem(COSName.FONT_NAME);

             fontFileCache.computeIfAbsent(fontName.getName(), key -> 
               fontFile.getItem(COSName.FONT_FILE2));
                          fontFile.setItem(COSName.FONT_FILE2, 
                     fontFileCache.get(fontName.getName()));
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }else {

         System.out.println("pageDictionary is null - likely Converted PDF 
           from Tiff");
      }
  }

  final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  doc.save(baos);
  final File compressed = new 
      File("C:\\Test\\PdfBox_Examples\\test_compressed.pdf");
  baos.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(compressed));

  System.out.println("Documents compressed");

 }
 }
```

//Note: I have also tested using tiff_1.pdf and tiff_2.pdf as the inputs.

Comment: "basically the total size of the all PDFs" - yes, that is what one would expect. There are commercial tools to reduce size. PDFBox does not have such builtin features. It can sometimes reduce sizes when it knows about flaws in a PDF.

Comment: *"I found a stackoverflow link [How to reduce the size of merged PDF/A-1b files with pdfbox or other java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420344/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-merged-pdf-a-1b-files-with-pdfbox-or-other-java-library). But it did not seem to help."* - The code there works when you merge files with *identical* objects, e.g. multiple copies of the same document with minute changes. For merely *similar* objects it does not work. In my answer there I explicitly said so.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. I will take a look iText to see the difference and if we can afford it.