# Heap space issue while merging the document using pdfBox

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, pdfbox

I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemory error when I am trying to merge one 44k pages pdf. I am fetching all the 44k pages from my DB in chunks and trying to merge with my main document. It is processing fine till 9.5k pages and then it start throwing heap space error.

```
public void getDocumentAsPdf(String docid) {

       

        PDDocument pdDocument = new PDDocument();

        try {

            //fetching total count from DB
            Long totalPages = countByDocument(docid);
            Integer batchSize = 400;
            Integer skip=0;
            Long totalBatches = totalPages/batchSize;
            Long remainingPages = totalPages%batchSize;

            for (int i = 1; i <= totalBatches; i++) {
                
                log.info("Batch : {}", i );
                
                //fetching pages of given document in ascending order from database
                List<Page> documentPages = fetchPagesByDocument(document,batchSize,
                        skip);
                pdDocument = mergePagesToDocument(pdDocument,documentPages);
                skip+=batchSize;
            }

            if(remainingPages>0)
            {
                //fetching remaining pages of given document in ascending order from database
                List<Page> documentPages = fetchPagesByDocument(document,batchSize,skip);
                pdDocument = mergePagesToDocument(pdDocument,documentPages);
            }

           
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
         
            throw new InternalErrorException("500","Exception occurred while merging! ");
        }

        
    }
```

Merge pdf logic

```
public PDDocument mergePagesToDocument(PDDocument pdDocument,List<Page> documentPages)  {

        try {
            PDFMergerUtility pdfMergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();
            pdfMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
            for (Page page : documentPages) {
                byte[] decodedPage = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(page.getPageData());
                PDDocument addPage = PDDocument.load(decodedPage);
                pdfMergerUtility.appendDocument(pdDocument, addPage);
                addPage.close();
            }
            return pdDocument;
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
      
            throw new InternalErrorException("500",e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

I think there is some memory leak from my side which is causing the given issue. Any suggestion or any better approach for the same will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly a memory leak, but you are trying to store whole 44k pages PDF in pdDocument variable. It might be bigger than your heap size. You can increase it with VM option `-Xmx` (read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard)).

Alternatively you can change your approach to not load 44k pages into memory at once.

Comment: Thank you Pekinek for response. Can you please elaborate your alternate point little bit how can I merge all 44k pages without loading into memory at once?

Comment: I'm not PDFBox expert, but looks like it can be achieved with:
pdfMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());

More details here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/io/MemoryUsageSetting.html#setupTempFileOnly()

Comment: I had already tried the given approach but sadly it doesn't work for me