# How to reduce the size of split PDF document in PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox to split the pages of documents into multiple documents. But the size of the split document is very large.

For example, I am performing split operation on 16k pages PDF and splitting it into 16k documents and each document contains one page. The size of each page document is 289kb. So, overall it is occupying around 4gb of space to store all the split documents on disk.

```java
import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter; 
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Iterator;
  
public class SplitPages {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      //Loading an existing PDF document
      File file = new File("sample.pdf");
      PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file); 

      //Instantiating Splitter class
      Splitter splitter = new Splitter();

      //splitting the pages of a PDF document
      List<PDDocument> Pages = splitter.split(document);

      //Creating an iterator 
      Iterator<PDDocument> iterator = Pages.listIterator();

      //Saving each page as an individual document
      int i = 1;
      while(iterator.hasNext()) {
         PDDocument pd = iterator.next();
         pd.save("sample"+ i++ +".pdf");
      }
      System.out.println("Multiple PDF’s created");
      document.close();
   }
}
```

How to optimize the splitted documents so that it will occupy less space on disk?

Note: I want to optimize the document while performing the split operation as mentioned in the code sample.

Comment: You may need to bring in other libraries such as this one https://www.qoppa.com/pdfoptimizer/ (it is paid). I'm not sure that you can do what you want with pdfbox itself.

Comment: Thank you for response, is it not possible to optimize or compress the size of splitted documents with pdf box? As of now, I am trying with non commercial libraries. If you suggest any, would be helpful

Comment: Looking into the documentation it seems there is a way to do it using pdfbox features, you will need to experiment to see if the result will still meet your requirements though. Here is one example of it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53544377/460557 and there is also   PreflightConfiguration which you can tweak to your needs

Comment: To answer your question for PDFBox we'd need to know why the size explodes like that. There actually are several possible reasons. E.g. your original PDF might contain an image used on all the pages; after splitting each page document will include a copy of that image. In that case you can hardly optimize...

Comment: @JorgeCampos, I had already tried the mentioned approach. It is optimizing when we perform merge operation but some issue with split operation. Can you please elaborate little bit more on Preflight configuration it would be helpful?

Comment: @mkl no it is a simple pdf only. Thank you for response, I will check the same.

Comment: @life888888  It is helpful but the answer is explained in theoretical manner.

Comment: And add to @KJ comment, it is likely that your PDF have images (that's the OCR part) on it which is causing the size to this big. Like I mentioned before, I just read the documentation I was not even aware it is possible. Looked on google and here is one example: https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.apache.pdfbox.preflight.PreflightConfiguration
You also might want to try other approaches if the case is PDF with images, there are free tool for linux (assuming your server is a linux) you could generate the PDF splits and then go through the OS level to reduce its size using some tool.

Comment: Here is a thread with such tools: https://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-scanned-pdf-file

Comment: @KJ you can try with any pdf document. I can't share the actual document due to security reasons. For example: https://freeditorial.com/en/books/50-shades-of-grey/downloadbookepub?format2=pdf The actual size of pdf is 2 mb but the split pages occupying 30 mb of space as combine in the disk. I hope you get my question. I am trying to optimize the split documents, so it occupies less space in disk.

Comment: Thank you @JorgeCampos I will check into it.

Comment: For 50 shades of grey.pdf it is working little bit different 585 Files occupying 32,100,000 bytes but for 16k pages pdf mentioned in my post it is working exactly same as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions and help. I had searched a lot and found that pdfbox lacking somewhere in compression related things, itext library can be better alternate for the same problem but the only problem is it cannot be used as open source as of now.  If anyone still found any solution with pdfbox can share it here. It would be helpful for others.

Comment: There are embedded fonts in your example file that are copied into each split file again and again. Thus, the size is very likely to explode upon splitting.

Comment: Thank you @mkl for update. Is there any way to optimize it as each document consist of single page? I had tried with the answer you had given here stackoverflow.com/a/53544377/460557. It is working good while performing merge operation.

Comment: The results could be improved by reducing the embedded fonts copied to the single page PDFs to the glyphs actually used on the respective page. There are no high-level methods in PDFBox for that but there are the low level methods you'd need to implement such a high level method. You'd have to walk all the content streams used for that page and determine the character codes used there and then rebuild the embedded font accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you. I will try it. If you have any sample code for reference, you can add it here.