# Remove duplicate embedded subsets of font in PDFs

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox-2.0.24 to merge multiple PDFs. However, the merged file size is too large because it contains many duplicate embedded subsets of font. For an example, I merge 1.pdf and 2.pdf which shows some repeated font list as picture1.

[image]

I tried the source code provided by mkl : ([How to reduce the size of merged PDF/A-1b files with pdfbox or other java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420344/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-merged-pdf-a-1b-files-with-pdfbox-or-other-java-librar/53544377#53544377))

However, it is not working for me. Can anyone have an idea to remove the duplicate embedded subsets of font in merging PDFs?

Comment: How do you know that the subset is the exact same?

Comment: Indeed, that my old answer you referenced does not make a difference, is a sign that there are differences in those subsets.

Comment: Thank you for the precise responses from Tilman, mkl and KJ,  which have helped me clear my mind. It seems that the "same" subset are not identical, and there is no solution to reduce internal duplication.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Is it possible for creating a New PDF with embedding FULL set of font? e.g. A PDF is added "Hello World" with Font source - Calibri.tff. Can pdfBox embedded the whole Calibri.tff as a embedded subset of font? So I can reduce the same "FULL" subset of font?

Comment: I don't know if this would work. I have never tried this with non-simple fonts. You could try it by replacing the font in the resources. The problem is that the final file might still be bigger because many fonts are huge.