# How to reduce the size of merged PDF files with pdfbox 3.0.0

Tags: pdf, optimization, memory, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 3.0.0 with java 17 to merge many PDF documents.

The file sources that will be merged are converted in advance with GhostScript from some normal PDFs to PDF with images for each page. Each page of each PDF is an image afetr converting the PDFs with Ghostscript.

I have sometimes the same files that will be merged.
For exemple, I want the merge input-gs.pdf, input2-gs.pdf and the first file input-gs.pdf another time.

When I merge these files, the size of the output is bigg and it's not optimized.

I want to reduce the size of the file merged PDF, I am searching if there is a possibility to use the same images one time in all the PDF in the dictionary and use its reference without charging all the images in memory.

I search if there is a solution to set a key or an unique name for each image in the final merged PDF and use these names or references for the images later for merging the same file another time.

```
 private static void mergeFiles() throws IOException {
    RandomAccessStreamCache.StreamCacheCreateFunction streamCache =
        IOUtils.createMemoryOnlyStreamCache();
    PDDocument emptyDocument = createBlankValidDocument();
    
    PDFMergerUtility pdfMergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();
    pdfMergerUtility.setDocumentMergeMode(
        PDFMergerUtility.DocumentMergeMode.OPTIMIZE_RESOURCES_MODE);
    pdfMergerUtility.setAcroFormMergeMode(PDFMergerUtility.AcroFormMergeMode.JOIN_FORM_FIELDS_MODE);

    appendFile("input-gs.pdf", streamCache, emptyDocument, pdfMergerUtility);
    appendFile("input2-gs.pdf", streamCache, emptyDocument, pdfMergerUtility);
    appendFile("input-gs.pdf", streamCache, emptyDocument, pdfMergerUtility);

    emptyDocument.save("output-merged.pdf");
}

private static void appendFile(String filename,
                              RandomAccessStreamCache.StreamCacheCreateFunction streamCache,
                              PDDocument emptyDocument,
                              PDFMergerUtility pdfMergerUtility) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(new RandomAccessReadBuffer(new FileInputStream(file)),
                                         streamCache);
    pdfMergerUtility.appendDocument(emptyDocument, document);
}

public static PDDocument createBlankValidDocument() {
    try {
        RandomAccessStreamCache.StreamCacheCreateFunction streamCache =
            IOUtils.createMemoryOnlyStreamCache();
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument(streamCache);

        // Conformance level + Part
        XMPMetadata xmp = XMPMetadata.createXMPMetadata();
        PDFAIdentificationSchema id = xmp.createAndAddPDFAIdentificationSchema();
        id.setConformance("A");
        id.setPart(1);

        // Metadata
        setMetadata(document, xmp);
        
        return document;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}
private static void setMetadata(PDDocument document, XMPMetadata xmp)
    throws TransformerException, IOException {
    PDDocumentCatalog catalogue = document.getDocumentCatalog();
    XmpSerializer serializer = new XmpSerializer();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    serializer.serialize(xmp, outputStream, true);

    PDMetadata metadata = new PDMetadata(document);
    metadata.importXMPMetadata(outputStream.toByteArray());
    catalogue.setMetadata(metadata);
}
```

I have found a code in this post [How to reduce the size of merged PDF/A-1b files with pdfbox or other java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420344/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-merged-pdf-a-1b-files-with-pdfbox-or-other-java-librar) that search complexed objects in a file and merge it, I want if possible find a solution that will not use a lot of memory because I will have sometimes 100 files with many pages.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With Ghostscript, I am using it just to convert the initial PDFs to PDF that contains an image for each page, each page will be an image. After this, I will merge them with Pdfbox.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, you are re-using the same file (or pages from the same file), then the image objects produced should be identical.

Try `cpdf -squeeze out.pdf -o out2.pdf` on your output, to test this hypothesis. If this is indeed what is happening, the identical objects will be merged, and the size will reduce to what you expect.

(Cpdf's merger, by the way, should share the data properly if you use ranges from a file several times. For example, `cpdf a.pdf 1-3 b.pdf a.pdf 1-10 c.pdf` should include the contents of a.pdf pages 1-3 only once, even though those pages appear twice in the output).

Comment: I need to merge them with PDFBox, I write some texts on the images with Java.